# Express server is loading the app only the first time on port localhost:3000

Tags: node.js, express

I'm just starting with `node.js` and `express.js` and trying to create a listener with port 3000 using `app.listen(3000)`.

The problem I'm having is when I first load the app, the browser loads it just fine, but when I make some changes, save the file and reload the browser, it doesn't show any changes. Mean it is just showing the first loaded version.

I have read many Q/A but none provide the specific solution. I don't know what I'm missing or doing wrong. Any help would be much appreciated, or please let me know if I explained my question properly.

Comment: Clear your browser cache and check in network tab (Disable cache checked).

Comment: Still the same problem. It's not detecting new changes and giving old copy (previous loaded version)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are looking for a tool like [nodemon](https://github.com/remy/nodemon) which does the server reloading. Unfortunately, nodemon doesn't reload the page itself, you still have to do it manually. Perhaps [browsersync](https://browsersync.io/) can help with that: it can be used for frontend development with live reloading, but I'm not sure if it works for fullstack reloading. The setup may depend on your pipeline (gulp/webpack/...), see for instance, [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/q/37014942/3995261) for nodemon + gulp + browsersync combination.

Comment: Thank you very much, it worked. Sure, I'll post here if I found any tool I will find

Comment: @AbdulR. see the edit, browsersync is probably the next tool to look at

Answer (score 1):

you have to restart the server or install nodemon

Answer (score 0):

This might be a problem with your computer console, probably be an old mac, because I face the same problem as well, try and destroy all node action by using `killall node` for mac and for window computer `taskkill /im node.exe /F` this will terminate all node action on your computer, after restart the node server this should work if it doesn't kindly comment below